# How to insert a break every 3 sentences in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 1 paragraph.

> Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3. Sentence 4. Sentence 5. Sentence
>   6. Sentence 7.

After make new break. It will be become:

```
Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3. 
Sentence 4. Sentence 5. Sentence 6. 
Sentence 7.
```

How to do that ? Thanks !

Comment: You mean a _line break_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((?:.*?\.\s+)(?:.*?\.\s+)(?:.*?\.))\s*
```

Try this.Replace by `$1\n`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/27

or

```
((?:.*?\.\s+){3})\s*
```

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/26

You can scale to `20` as well.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked like a charm. However, If I want to add break every 20 sentences, how to do it ?

Comment: @TungKhongMinh use `((?:.*?\.\s+){20})\s*`.